# Will the product of these two matrices be unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ is a unitary matrix of order $m$.

$V$ is a unitary matrix of order $m-1$.

Let $V’$ be the a matrix of order $m$, constructed as $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & V \end{array} \right)$.

Is $UV’$ also unitary?

Answer (score 0):

$V'$ is unitary, therefore yes.

Comment: Ah yes. And then $UV’$ being unitary follows from the fact that product of two unitary matrices is always unitary?

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.